# Get current version of package outside of Visual Studio

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

We are migrating over to using packages and NuGet for managing our dependencies on 3rd party components.  This works well when referencing packages from within Visual Studio or building on the build server via msbuild.
However there are a number of files that we would like to access in our build scripts and installers.  Previously these would be in source control with a well known path, now as the version of the package that we are consuming changes so the path to the package and hence the files is changing.

Is there a simple way I can get the path to a given package?  The best solution I currently have is to search for all packages.config files and extract the package version from them.

Examples of the files that we need to access are

The NUnit console executable from the NUnit.Runners package for running unit tests.
License files from various packages that we redistribute with our installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the packages.config file is a pretty good solution. NuGet itself uses two approaches:

1. Reading the package information from the packages.config and using that to resolve to the packages path.
2. Enumerating all the directories in the packages directory.

You could use [NuGet.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nuget.Core/) to do either of the above if you do not want to write the code yourself. The classes that can be used are the DefaultPackagePathResolver, the PackageReferenceFile and LocalPackageRepository or SharedPackageRepository.

One problem with the second approach is that sometimes NuGet may occasionally leave behind NuGet packages that are not necessarily referenced by a project. In that case looking at the package directories may give you the incorrect information.

The only other approach I can think of might be to read the project files looking for the assembly references. Although that would not work for a solution level package such as NUnit.Runners.